# Disabling back button animation in NavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I was trying to disable the slide animation when I tap the back button in Navigation Controller.

So I subclassed *UINavigationController* and did the following:

```
- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    return [super popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

And it worked well except that the **back button** itself is still animating toward the center of the navigation controller.

I want my back button to just fade out just like the Calendar app in iOS7.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that animation is probably coming from the UINavigationBars method `popNavigationItemAnimated`, though I'm not sure how you would disable it.  Subclassing wouldn't work the same way your UINavigationController subclass worked because you couldn't tell your nav controller to instantiate an instance of your subclass.

Instead what I think you could do is inside your implementation of popViewController before you call super hide the back button.

```
- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    UINavigationItem *topItem = self.navigationBar.topItem;
    //if this doesn't work you could try the leftBarButtons array to nil 
    topItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    return [super popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Comment: I've managed to subclass UINavigationBar and instantiated it using **initWithNavigationBarClass:toolbarClass:** method and disabled the item animation neatly. Although the item just gone off instead of fading out, I definitely was able to set the start point thanks to you.

Comment: I didn't even think about initWithNavigationBarClass!  Glad it works.